# How was this substituted?

Tags: integration, substitution

A while ago, I saw a post for a [solution of the time of the brachistochrone](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1773469/386889). Sadly, I do not get how the integral shown was substituted. Can anybody help?

The original integral was

$$T=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2g}}\int_0^b \sqrt{\frac{1+(y'(x))^2}{y(x)}}dx$$

with

$$\frac{dx}{d\theta}=A(1-\cos\theta)$$

and

$$\frac{dy}{dθ}=A\sinθ$$

With $$x=A(\theta - \sin\theta)$$ and $$y=A(1-\cos\theta)$$ one came to the solution

$$\begin{align}T&=\sqrt{\frac 1{2g}}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta_0}\sqrt{\frac{1+(y')^2}y}\frac{dx}{d\theta}\,d\theta\\&=\sqrt{\frac A{2g}}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta_0}\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}{1-\cos\theta}}\,d\theta\\&=\sqrt{\frac Ag}\int_{\theta=0}^{\theta_0}\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos\theta}{1-\cos\theta}}\,d\theta\\&=\sqrt{\frac Ag}\theta_0.
\end{align}$$

Solving this is no problem. But I do not get, how the integral was changed.

Comment: Sorry Anne, I typed the wrong thing first. Now you got it.

Comment: Yes @AnneBauval , that is the right link :) Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Okay, so the step for $$y'(x)$$ is clear for me. What troubles me is the $$y(x)$$ which seems to be just $$=y(\theta)$$. Is that right? And then with substitution rule it follows $$\tfrac{dx}{d\theta} d\theta$$. Correct? And $$b=\theta$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\sqrt{\frac{1+(y')^2}y}\frac{dx}{d\theta}&=\sqrt{\frac{1+\left(\frac{A\sin\theta}{A(1-\cos\theta)}\right)^2}{A(1-\cos\theta)}}A(1-\cos\theta)\\&=\sqrt A\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos\theta)^2+\sin^2\theta}{1-\cos\theta}}\\&=\sqrt{2A}.
\end{align}$$
And $\theta_0$ is determined by
$$b=x(\theta_0)=A(\theta_0-\sin\theta_0).$$

Comment: Thank you so much Anne, it really really really means a lot!!!