# Given uniform gravity and time, find the farthest reachable distance x

Tags: calculus, physics, calculus-of-variations

I am writing a program where you chose where a particle starts and the particle is moving in a given graph under uniform gravity for a given amount of time. For my setup, this program needs a range of values $x$ to load the graph and calculate its derivatives for particle movement. However I am having problems finding the upper bounds for values $x$ which load the graph.

I assume the answer is some kind of [Brachistochrone curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachistochrone_curve), as it says in Wikipedia:

> Brachistochrone curve or curve of fastest descent, is the one lying on the plane between a point A and a lower point B, where B is not directly below A, on which a bead slides frictionlessly under the influence of a uniform gravitational field to a given end point in the shortest time.

Since in needs the least amount of time to travel to another point, the curve which will travel the furthest in the $x$ direction given some time $t$ is also a Brachistochrone? I found in another [math stack answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1773469) that the time to travel the whole Brachistochrone is 
$T = \sqrt{\frac{A}{g}}\theta_o$, where $A$ is the radius of the rolling circle, $g$ is the gravitational acceleration and $\theta_o$ is the parameter angle for the rolling circle to make one roll with constant speed, which is equal to $2 \pi$. For example, in the horizontal case I can express $A = \frac{T^2g}{\theta_o^2}$ and $x = 2\pi A$, thus $x = \frac{T^2g}{\theta_o}$, but what if the end point is at a lower height? How can this time equation be written if the line slant of the rolling circle with constant speed is other than horizontal? I think in the slanted case the parameter $A$ increases, but then you need to project it back to the x-plane. How can this be done?

Comment: Are you interested in _some_ upper bound? In that case: Let $T$ be the given amount of time. Suppose your particle dropped vertically (ignoring the graph) for the duration of $T$, giving you a vertical distance $y_0$. You can bound $x<y_0$, since the particle on the graph will never travel faster in the $x$-direction than in free fall.

Comment: @DominikS Oh, that's clever! I currently was searching for bounds with conservation of energy, but some graphs, like 1/x are always decreasing in the range $x \in (0; +\infty)$, this could be the other bound algorithm for now, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're saying that this problem is similar to the Brachistochrone problem.  It seems to me that the total time that the particle is allowed to travel is fixed, and you're just trying to find the particle's trajectory, which is isn't the Brachistochrone problem.  It might also be better to quantitatively express by what you mean by "moving in a given graph", "load the graph", etc.